# setting date of datepicker fuelux

Tags: datepicker, fuelux

I need to initialize or set a specific date in the datepicker of fuelux.

The DatePicker component works placing today's date by default , but I need set the first of January 2015 (for example "01-01-2015").

The Code js.

$('#myDatepicker1').datepicker({
    allowPastDates: true,
    momentConfig: {
        culture: 'es',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    },
    restricted: [
        {from: '01-01-2013', to: '01-01-2014'}
    ]
});

In advance thanks for the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setDate` method.

`$('#myDatepicker').datepicker('setDate', '01-01-2015');` [View documentation](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#datepicker-usage-methods-set-date).